# is it possible to make a base 60 float

Tags: csv, datetime, matplotlib, time

I currently have code that plots data from a CSV using matplotlib. The problem is the math I am trying to run is time dependant, and when I set my x-axis to float(time.strftime("%M%S")), using the datetime module, there's a gap in the plotted graph between 60-100, as the time value is base 60, unlike the base 10 float number system, so is there any way to fix this, by making the float base 60?

apologies for the rush

Comment: why don't you use a numeric, continuous representation of time, e.g. seconds since x ?

Comment: why are you converting to a float? matplotlib can plot with datatime on the x axis

Comment: convert M and S separately, and just `M + S/60`. You have a lot of simple solution. I wonder why the idea of "base 60 float" (ok, what I did it is just a base 60 calculation, but it is simpler to interpret as minute, seconds, then thinking about base 60)

Comment: Also be aware of leap seconds :) - for example 23:59:60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert M and S separately, and just M + S/60. You have a lot of simple solution. I wonder why the idea of "base 60 float" (ok, what I did it is just a base 60 calculation, but it is simpler to interpret as minute, seconds, then thinking about base 60)
-Giacomo Catenazzi